# set val of html string in jquery loop with val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I take this string v that is in a loop and use jquery to add the value to the input id "MyInput"

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
var d='';

    $.each(row,function(i,v){

        //v = <div><p>gxsfsd</p><p>gxsfsd</p><input  type="hidden" id="Myinput" /><p>gxsfsd</p><p>gxsfsd</p><p>gxsfsd</p></div>"

    $(v).find("#MyInput").val("text set 1");

    d+= v;

    });
```

Comment: can you give an example of your whole row object? Is it an array with this HTML string multiple times or is it a jQuery collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
var d='';

$.each(row,function(i,v){
   d += v;
   $('#MyInput').val(d);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element directly and not need to find when you know id of control, provided if the id is unique.

Try this,

```
var d='';

$.each(row,function(i,v){
   d+= v;
   $("#MyInput").val(d);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same id more than once in the page, you will have problems accessing the elements.

It's still possible if you use an attribute selector instead of an id selector:

```
var d='';

$.each(row,function(i,v){

  //v = <div><p>gxsfsd</p><p>gxsfsd</p><input  type="hidden" id="Myinput" /><p>gxsfsd</p><p>gxsfsd</p><p>gxsfsd</p></div>"

  $(v).find("[id=MyInput]").val("text set 1");

  d+= v;

});
```

Comment: Plus, change the ID to a class

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, use classes instead of the same ID multiple times, or even leave them both if you have the context anyway... I'd do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrFzy/):

```
var d = [], // collect in an array for better handling
    row = $('.row');

$.each(row, function(i,v){
    var input = $('input', $(v));
    input.val("text set "+i);
    d.push(v);
});

console.log(d);
```

Note that my HTML with .row divs works just as an example, as soon as I know what kind of object your "row" is, I might adjust this solution.